# using the directshow to control the camera and using open cv to capture images

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow

i am using the directshow to control the camera settings and using open cv i am capturing the images..but my problem is when i capture the images the images settings which i give changes after 2 or 3 captures and turns to a default value...i need this for my college project,,,i have given my code below...i always want a image with same camera settings...the solution given by you will be highly helpfull because i am completely new to this..

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <atlstr.h> 
    #include <dshow.h> 
    #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
    #include <opencv\cv.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <streams.h>

     CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[1];
      int g_cTemplates;



     void setCameraMode(ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pCaptureGraphBuilder2, IAMStreamConfig *pConfig,      IBaseFilter *pDeviceFilter, HRESULT hr)    
{ 

     // Set res, frame rate, and color mode 

                hr = CoInitialize(0); 

                hr = pCaptureGraphBuilder2->FindInterface(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, 0, pDeviceFilter, IID_IAMStreamConfig, (void**)&pConfig); 


                int iCount = 0, iSize = 0; 

                hr = pConfig->GetNumberOfCapabilities(&iCount, &iSize); 

    // Check the size to make sure we pass in the correct structure.

                if (iSize == sizeof(VIDEO_STREAM_CONFIG_CAPS)) 
                { 

    // Use the video capabilities structure. 

                        for (int iFormat = 0; iFormat < iCount; iFormat++) 
                        { 

                                VIDEO_STREAM_CONFIG_CAPS scc; 
                                AM_MEDIA_TYPE *pmtConfig; 
                                hr = pConfig->GetStreamCaps(iFormat, &pmtConfig, (BYTE*)&scc); 

                                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
                                { 
                                       if ((pmtConfig->majortype == MEDIATYPE_Video)) //&& 
                                                //(pmtConfig->subtype == MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24))
                                        { 

                                        VIDEOINFOHEADER *pVih = (VIDEOINFOHEADER*)pmtConfig->pbFormat; 

    // pVih contains the detailed format information. 

                                        LONG lWidth = pVih->bmiHeader.biWidth; 
                                        LONG lHeight = pVih->bmiHeader.biHeight; 
                                        pVih->bmiHeader.biWidth = 160;
                                        pVih->bmiHeader.biHeight = 120;
                                        pVih->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = DIBSIZE(pVih->bmiHeader);

                                      //  pVih->AvgTimePerFrame = 10000000;
                                       }
                                } 

                                        hr = pConfig->SetFormat(pmtConfig); 
                                        hr = pConfig->GetStreamCaps(iFormat, &pmtConfig, (BYTE*)&scc);
                                        //DeleteMediaType(pmtConfig);
                         } 

               } 


} 





          void setCameraControl(IBaseFilter *pDeviceFilter, HRESULT hr, int exposure, int focus)    
{ 

  // Query the capture filter for the IAMCameraControl interface. 

        IAMCameraControl *pCameraControl = 0; 
        hr = pDeviceFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IAMCameraControl, (void**)&pCameraControl); 
        if (FAILED(hr)) 
        { 

 // The device does not support IAMCameraControl 

        } 

        else 
        { 

        long Min, Max, Step, Default, Flags, Val; 

  // Get the range and default values 

         hr = pCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Exposure, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
         hr = pCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Focus, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
                { 
                  hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Exposure, -10, CameraControl_Flags_Manual );

 // Min = -11, Max = 1, Step = 1 

                  hr = pCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Focus, focus, CameraControl_Flags_Manual ); 
                } 

        } 

} 





           void setCameraProperties(IBaseFilter *pDeviceFilter, HRESULT hr, int brightness, int backLightCompensation, int contrast, int saturation, int sharpness, int whiteBalance)   
{ 

 // Query the capture filter for the IAMVideoProcAmp interface. 

        IAMVideoProcAmp *pProcAmp = 0; 
        hr = pDeviceFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IAMVideoProcAmp, (void**)&pProcAmp); 
        if (FAILED(hr)) 
        { 

 // The device does not support IAMVideoProcAmp 

        } 

        else 
        { 

          long Min, Max, Step, Default, Flags, Val; 

 // Get the range and default values 

          hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Brightness, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
          hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_BacklightCompensation, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
          hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Contrast, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
          hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Saturation, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
          hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Sharpness, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
          hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_WhiteBalance, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
                { 
                   hr = pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_Brightness,100, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual); 
                   hr = pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_BacklightCompensation, 0, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual); 
                   hr = pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_Contrast, 20 , VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual); 
                   hr = pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_Saturation,50, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual); 
                   hr = pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_Sharpness, 0, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual); 
                   hr = pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_WhiteBalance, 0, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual); 
                } 

        } 

} 





//given in the example program

        IPin *GetPin(IBaseFilter *pFilter, PIN_DIRECTION PinDir) 
{ 
    BOOL       bFound = FALSE; 
    IEnumPins  *pEnum; 
    IPin       *pPin; 

    pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnum); 
    while(pEnum->Next(1, &pPin, 0) == S_OK) 
    { 
        PIN_DIRECTION PinDirThis; 
        pPin->QueryDirection(&PinDirThis); 
        if (bFound = (PinDir == PinDirThis)) 
            break; 
        pPin->Release(); 
    } 
    pEnum->Release(); 
    return (bFound ? pPin : 0);   
} 





      int main() 
{ 
//  for playing 
        IGraphBuilder *pGraphBuilder; 
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pCaptureGraphBuilder2; 
        IMediaControl *pMediaControl = NULL; 
        IMediaEventEx *pEvent = NULL;
        //  multiple cameras 
        IBaseFilter *pDeviceFilter_0 = NULL; 
        IBaseFilter *m_pGrabber_0 = NULL; 
        ISampleGrabber *m_pGrabberSettings_0 = NULL; 


        //  select camera 
        ICreateDevEnum *pCreateDevEnum = NULL; 
        IEnumMoniker *pEnumMoniker = NULL; 
        IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL; 
        ULONG nFetched = 0; 
        // initialize COM 
        CoInitialize(NULL); 

        // selecting a device 
        // Create CreateDevEnum to list device 
        std::string USB1 = "\\\\?\\usb#vid_045e&pid_076d&mi_00#7&1ba27d43&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\\global"; 


        CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICreateDevEnum, (PVOID *)&pCreateDevEnum); 

        // Create EnumMoniker to list VideoInputDevice 
        pCreateDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEnumMoniker, 0); 
        if (pEnumMoniker == NULL) { 
        // this will be shown if there is no capture device 
        printf("no device\n"); 
        return 0; 
        } 

        // reset EnumMoniker 
        pEnumMoniker->Reset(); 

        // get each Moniker 
        while (pEnumMoniker->Next(1, &pMoniker, &nFetched) == S_OK)
        { 
                IPropertyBag *pPropertyBag; 
                TCHAR devname[256]; 
                TCHAR devpath[256]; 

                // bind to IPropertyBag 
                pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void **)&pPropertyBag); 

                VARIANT var; 

                // get FriendlyName 
                var.vt = VT_BSTR; 
                pPropertyBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, 0); 
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, var.bstrVal, -1, devname, sizeof(devname), 0, 0); 
                VariantClear(&var); 

                // get DevicePath 
                // DevicePath : A unique string 

                var.vt = VT_BSTR; 

                pPropertyBag->Read(L"DevicePath", &var, 0); 

                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, var.bstrVal, -1, devpath, sizeof(devpath), 0, 0); 

                std::string devpathString = devpath; 

                pMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pDeviceFilter_0 ); 


                pMoniker->Release(); 
                pPropertyBag->Release(); 

                if (pDeviceFilter_0 == NULL) 
                { 
                        MessageBox(NULL, "No MS HD-5000 cameras found", "No cameras", MB_OK); 
                        return 0; 
                } 

        } 

        // create FilterGraph and CaptureGraphBuilder2 
        CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IGraphBuilder, (LPVOID *)&pGraphBuilder); 
        CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (LPVOID *)&pCaptureGraphBuilder2); 

        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0); 
        IAMStreamConfig *pConfig = NULL; 
        setCameraMode(pCaptureGraphBuilder2,  pConfig,  pDeviceFilter_0,  hr);  //  FPS, Res, color mode 
        setCameraControl(pDeviceFilter_0, hr, 10 , 12); //  Focus, exposure 
        setCameraProperties(pDeviceFilter_0, hr, 180, 0, 4, 100, 0, 2800);  //  Brightness, saturation, etc 



        //  set grabber properties 
        AM_MEDIA_TYPE mt; 
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter,                                                               (void**)&m_pGrabber_0);   // create ISampleGrabber 
        pCaptureGraphBuilder2->SetFiltergraph(pGraphBuilder);   // set FilterGraph 
        pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (LPVOID *)&pMediaControl); // get MediaControl interface 

        m_pGrabber_0->QueryInterface(IID_ISampleGrabber, (void**)&m_pGrabberSettings_0); 

      ZeroMemory(&mt, sizeof(AM_MEDIA_TYPE)); 
      mt.majortype = MEDIATYPE_Video; 
      mt.subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24; 
      hr = m_pGrabberSettings_0->SetMediaType(&mt); 

       if (FAILED(hr)) 
      { 
                 return hr; 
       } 
        hr = m_pGrabberSettings_0->SetOneShot(FALSE); 
        hr = m_pGrabberSettings_0->SetBufferSamples(TRUE); 


        //  build filter graph 
       pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pDeviceFilter_0, L"Device Filter"); 
       pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(m_pGrabber_0, L"Sample Grabber"); 
       IPin* pSourceOut_0 = GetPin(pDeviceFilter_0, PINDIR_OUTPUT); 
       IPin* pGrabberIn_0 = GetPin(m_pGrabber_0, PINDIR_INPUT); 
       pGraphBuilder->Connect(pSourceOut_0, pGrabberIn_0); 

     /* 
           pMediaControl->Run(); 
           long pBufferSize;
           unsigned char* pBuffer_0 = 0;
           hr = m_pGrabberSettings_0->GetCurrentBuffer(&pBufferSize, NULL);
          if (FAILED(hr))
          {
              return 0;
          }

           pBuffer_0 = (BYTE*)CoTaskMemAlloc(pBufferSize);

           if (!pBuffer_0) 
          {
            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            return 0;
          }


          long pBufferSize = 0;
            unsigned char* pBuffer_0 = 0;
            long Size=0;
            hr = m_pGrabberSettings_0->GetCurrentBuffer(&Size, NULL);

            if (Size != pBufferSize)
            {
               pBufferSize = Size;

               if (pBuffer_0 != 0)
               {
                  delete[] pBuffer_0;
                 }

               pBuffer_0= new unsigned char[pBufferSize];
            }      


         long pBufferSize = 425; 
          unsigned char* pBuffer_0 = 0; 

          pBuffer_0 = new unsigned char[pBufferSize]; 



        // start playing 
          pMediaControl->Run(); 

        while (1)   { 

        if (MessageBox(NULL, "Grab frame?", "Grab?", MB_OKCANCEL) == 2) 
        { 
                break; 
        } 

        hr = m_pGrabberSettings_0->GetCurrentBuffer(&pBufferSize,(long*)pBuffer_0); 

    Cleanup: 

        //  convert to OpenCV format 

        IplImage* img_0 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(160,120),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3); 

        for (int i = 0; i < pBufferSize ; i++) 
        { 
                img_0->imageData[i] = pBuffer_0[i]; 
        } 

        cvFlip(img_0, NULL, 0); 



        //  show 
       // cvNamedWindow("mainWin_0", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
       // cvMoveWindow("mainWin_0", 100, 100); 
          cvShowImage("mainWin_0", img_0 ); 
          cvSaveImage("c:\\users\\senthil\\desktop\\img.png",img_0 );

        //cvWaitKey(0); 

        cvReleaseImage(&img_0 ); 

        } 

        */


    pMediaControl->Run(); 
    cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1);    //Create window
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);  //Capture using any camera connected to your system
    while(1)
    {
     //Create infinte loop for live streaming
        if (MessageBox(NULL, "Grab frame?", "Grab?", MB_OKCANCEL) == 2) 
        { 
                break; 
        } 

        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); //Create image frames from capture
        cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame);     //Show image frames on created window

        cvSaveImage("c:\\users\\senthil\\desktop\\img1.png",frame);


    //  cv::Mat img(frame);
    //  cv::imwrite("c:\\users\\selvaraj\\desktop\\img.png",img);

    }

    //std::cout << "FPS: " << fps << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "PROP_BRIGHTNESS: " << PROP_BRIGHTNESS << std::endl;
    //WriteComPort("COM3","A");
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture); //Release capture.
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output"); //Destroy Window                      */


        //  release 
        pMediaControl->Release(); 
        pCaptureGraphBuilder2->Release(); 
        pGraphBuilder->Release(); 
        pEnumMoniker->Release(); 
        pCreateDevEnum->Release(); 

        // finalize COM 
        CoUninitialize(); 

        return 0; 
}        


       i tried using the sample grabber also but it is also not usefull...help me to solve this code..
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about these settings:

```
    setCameraMode(pCaptureGraphBuilder2,  pConfig,  pDeviceFilter_0,  hr);  //  FPS, Res, color mode 
    setCameraControl(pDeviceFilter_0, hr, 10 , 12); //  Focus, exposure 
    setCameraProperties(pDeviceFilter_0, hr, 180, 0, 4, 100, 0, 2800);  //  Brightness, saturation, etc
```

Comment: yea @ vicky...these settings are not taken by the camera all the time

Comment: OK. I see an issue where you are setting the values. Soon after you are getting the current range, you must check for HRESULT and only then set the values. Else, you may write the logic to retry with different values.

Comment: @vicky...can u please give me an example of how to set the valuse for cam..i am using life cam HD 5000..

Comment: Sure! Just do something similar:

   hr = pProcAmp->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Brightness, &Min, &Max, &Step, &Default, &Flags); 
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
   { 
    if (brightness >= Min && brightness <= Max)
    {
     pProcAmp->Set(VideoProcAmp_Brightness, 100, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Manual);
    }
   }

Comment: @ vicky... thanks for your suggestion vicky...i tried it...but still only the first image is as per settings...from second image it again goes back to somne default values...

Comment: No worries. Check the behavior by using the graphEdit. Create or generate the graph from the code and play. Let me know.

Comment: @vicky...what do you mean by graph edit..thanks for your reply

Comment: It is a tool to simulate or to debug your filter graphs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx